# C# Чтение из массива

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

Помогите понять почему вылетает с ошибкой "System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат." и там идут дальше много строк, и ругается всё это после того как я пытаюсь из строкового массива зачитать данные в сообщении или установить их в Label, что я делаю не так?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace Test2
{
/// <summary>
/// Description of MainForm.
/// </summary>
///
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public static string path_file = Application.StartupPath + "\\data.ini";


    public static class Win32
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int MessageBox(int hWnd, String text,
            String caption, uint type); 
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(String sSection, String sKey, String sDefault,
            String sString, int iSize, String sFile);
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    public MainForm()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path_file))
        {
            Win32.MessageBox(0, "Файл с данными(data.ini) не найден! Найдите и установите файл в директорию программы, затем перезапуститесь!", "Уведомление", 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Win32.MessageBox(0, "Файл с данными(data.ini) найден! Удачной работы с программой!", "Уведомление", 0);
        }
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path_file))
        {
            Win32.MessageBox(0, "Файл с данными(data.ini) не был найден! Найдите и установите файл в директорию программы, затем перезапуститесь!", "Уведомление", 0);
            return;
        }

        //-----------
        int[] norm_time = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] lifeguard = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        string[] norm_name = { "easy", "moderate", "heavy", "very_heavy" };
        string[] key = { "text", "text" };
        //-----------
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            Win32.GetPrivateProfileString(norm_name[i], "time", "NULL", key[0], 100, path_file);
            Win32.GetPrivateProfileString(norm_name[i], "lifeguard", "NULL", key[1], 100, path_file);
            if(key[0] == "NULL" || key[1] == "NULL")
            {
                Win32.MessageBox(0, "Ключ 'time' раздела 'easy' не был найден в данных, проверьте целостность файла!", "Уведомление", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                norm_time[i] = Convert.ToInt32(key[0]);
                lifeguard[i] = Convert.ToInt32(key[1]);
            }
        }
        label12.Text = (lifeguard.GetValue(3)).ToString();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: А вы знаете, что такое `отладка` ? Это такая прекрасная вещь, где вы можете понаставить сотню точек остановки в нужных местах и узнать как живет ваше творение. Ищите где падает, ставьте точку, смотрите что отдаете функции и ищите что она принимает (к примеру `Convert.ToInt32()` не возьмет строку, которая содержит скажем такой текст - `"asdf"`, ибо нет цифр). В общем, учитесь искать информацию и тогда подобных вопросов будет меньше, гораздо меньше!

Comment: я юзаю цифры только, условие отлавливает строки с единственными буквами NULL, в самом конце кода падает от вызова конвертации цифр в строку, конкретно там косяк но я не понимаю что там не так, на прямую из обычных переменных всё работает шикарно, перевожу на массивы и такая белеберда...

Comment: Во первых, в вопросе все надо указывать (где ошибка, что подается и так далее, за вас гадать не будут), во вторых - посмотрите ЕЩЕ РАЗ, внимательней, поставьте точку остановки на строку `norm_time[i] = Convert.ToInt32(key[0]);` и посмотрите чему равен `key[0]`. Я вам даже скажу чему он будет равен - `"10\0t"` (если я не ошибаюсь, то это Нуль-терминированная строка, не знаю, есть ли стандартные методы для борьбы с ней, можете попробовать `.Split('\0')[0];`). Теперь вернемся к моему первому сообщению - учитесь проводить отладку вашего кода, это очень сильно сэкономит вам время!

Comment: Кстати, `ini` формат уж больно старый, не легче перейти на что нибудь новее? `JSON`? `XML`? Тогда и подобных трудностей не будет, в `API` лезть не придется и жизнь легче станет...

Comment: Зачем `null` в кавычках строка `if(key[0] == "NULL" || key[1] == "NULL")`

Comment: @VovkaNonsens  чтобы поставить brakepoint(точку останова): до запуска программы в IDE VisualStudio кликните ЛКМ по узкому полю слева на уровне интересующей строки -- там появиться красная точка; потом при выполнении программы она приостановиться, когда дойдёт до этого места, и внизу в отладчике будет видно список имеющихся на данный момент переменных и их текущее значение; ну и прямо в коде можно указатель мыши навести и значение "всплывёт"  :)

Comment: @Alias, а причём тут вижак когда я указал в теге sharpdevelop? =)

Comment: @Digital Core, там NULL потому что эту строку у меня возвращает когда ключ или секция не найдена, так как пробел и пустая строка не проверяется не как...
Да кстате код что ты предложил ругается на " StringBuilder"

Comment: @VovkaNonsens да, действительно. В остальном поддерживаю т.з. EvgeniyZ -- ставьте брейкпойнты и такие вопросы не возникнут...

Comment: "2\0\0t" показывает значение обоих key, что мне это даст? Split заюзал не чего не изменилось...

Comment: Digital Core, разобрался со всем кодом, всё работает спасибо =)
В будущем буду юзать xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Завалялся класс из древнего проекта, возможно поможет Вам, хотя рекомендую всё-же json!

```csharp
class Config
    {
        public string path;

        public Config(string INIPath)
        {
            path = INIPath;
        }

        public void Write(string Section, string Key, string Value)
        {
            NativeMethods.WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, path);
        }

        public string Read(string Section, string Key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = NativeMethods.GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp,
                                            255, path);
            return temp.ToString();
        }
    }

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        internal static extern int WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
            string key, string val, string filePath);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        internal static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
                 string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
            int size, string filePath);
    }
```

далее всё просто вызываете метод write, или read, примерно так:

```csharp
Config con = new Config(path);
var str = con.Read("section", "key"));
con.Write(section, key, value);
```

P/s и будет Вам счастье :-)